# Amazon S3 Missing Files

Tags: caching, amazon-s3

We're working on developing user widgets that our members can embed on their websites and blogs. To reduce the load on our servers we'd like to be able to compile the necessary data file for each user ahead of time and store it on our Amazon S3 account.

While that sounds simple enough, I'm hoping there might be a way for S3 to automatically ping our script if a file is requested that for some reason doesn't exist (say for instance if it failed to upload properly). Basically we want Amazon S3 to act as our cache and it to notify a script on a cache miss. I don't believe Amazon provides a way to do this directly but I was hoping that some hacker out there could come up with a smart way to accomplish this (such as mod_rewite, hash table, etc).

Thanks in advance for your help & advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon doesn't currently support this, but it [looks like it might be coming](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html). For now, what you could do is [enable logging](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html) and parse the log for 404s once an hour or so.

It's certainly not instant, but it would prevent long-term 404s and give you some visibility about what files are missing.

Comment: Understood that there doesn't seem to be an actual answer to this today but lets hope you're right and Amazon is going in that direction. Thanks!